# Adding custom datatable to chart object in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I was just wondering if there is a way to customize the content of a DataTable in a Chart-object in VBA? I.e. is there a way to alter the content of the table to NOT be the actual chart-data? See picture below, where *Pos* and *EU* (left-most pic) have been alterned into *OtherData1* and *OtherData2* (right-most pic), obviously with new data in the table as well. The data that need to go into the table is found in a range-object.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Just to clearify: The data that need to be going into the table is *independent* of the initial chart-data...

Comment: I've got a pretty neat solution for you, give me a few minutes to put together some screenshots/instructions.

Comment: @DavidZemens, did you see my comment or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a neat trick that I have used a *lot*.  It won't give you a table with borders, and you'll have to add textboxes for the series' names, but it will allow you to customize what appears in the "table" below the chart.
First, create your chart and add series for all data:

[image]

Add data labels, and then format the "Other Data" series so that there is no line, markers/etc.:

[image]

Then, you can use a macro like this to adjust the data labels' positions, relative to the chart/plot area.  For this macro, I simply check to see if the series' line format `.Visible = msoFalse`, but you could extend that logic to meet whatever additional requirements you might have.

```
Sub Test()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Series
Dim p As Long
Dim dl As DataLabel
Dim dlTop As Double
Dim s As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection
    If srs.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse Then
        s = s + 1
        srs.DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionCenter
        For p = 1 To srs.Points.Count
            Set dl = srs.DataLabels(p)
            dlTop = cht.PlotArea.Height + cht.PlotArea.Top + (s * dl.Height)
            dl.Select
            dl.Top = dlTop
        Next
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The result should be something like:

[image]

Comment: That was a neat solution @DavidZemens, useful indeed. However, I still don't get how you get the table-data into your chart? As far as I see it, you have only made  the other data invisible, and adjusted the data labels (but not added any table anywhere?). Thanks.

Comment: @gussilago Does it matter whether there *is* a "table" in the chart, as long as it *looks like* there is a table in the chart?  A table, after all, is merely an organized grid/array of data; positioning the labels in this manner gives the appearance of a table.

Comment: No, of course it does not matter. But in your code, where do you actually "add" the numbers that "become" your table? (0.68, 0.23 etc). How have you "pasted" them in?

Comment: I add these data to the chart when I create the chart, so for example, select the data range, and then from the Ribbon, Insert | Chart, then choose your chart type.  Then you have to format the series to be "invisible" before running the macro.

Comment: I see it now. Very nice! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I cannot get rid of the line in the data table that refers to the data seen, but I can add in more rows into the data table (numeric only)

Example:
[image: graph with multiple lines in the data table]

To do this, I added all the lines into the data for the graph, including the data I want to show only in the data table.
I then formatted the data lines for those that I don't want to show as *Marker Fill*: No Fill, and *Line Color*: No Line. This will make the line disappear.
I then adjusted the scale to make it look as if only one data line was plotted.